# Space-reflected solution of the Dirac equation

Tags: dirac-equation, parity

In Bjorken & Drell vol. 1 "Relativistic quantum mechanics",  the parity operator acting on solutions of the Dirac equation is represented as $P=e^{i\phi}\gamma^{0}$, where $\phi$ is a phase. Let's apply this operator to a solution of the equation with definite energy, momentum and spin $\psi$. At page 71 it is said that this operation inverts the spatial components of momentum and leaves the spin unchanged (as it should be, according to the classical picture of the system). But how to prove this explicitly?

I think that a solution should be:

1) Writing $\psi$ by means of the projection operator for energy and spin with some energy-momentum and polarization 4-vectors $p^{\mu}=(p^{0},\vec{p})$ and $s^{\mu}=(s^{0},\vec{s})$:

$$\psi=\left(\frac{\epsilon_{r}p_{\mu}\gamma^{\mu}+m}{2m}\right)\left(\frac{1+\gamma_{5}s_{\mu}\gamma^{\mu}}{2}\right)\psi$$

2) Acting with $P=e^{i\phi}\gamma^{0}$ on $\psi$ and, after using (anti-)commutation rules for gamma matrices, showing that be that $P\psi$ is an eigenfunction of the energy and spin projection operator with proper momentum and polarization 4-vectors, i.e.

$$P\psi=\left(\frac{\epsilon_{r}p'_{\mu}\gamma^{\mu}+m}{2m}\right)\left(\frac{1+\gamma_{5}s'_{\mu}\gamma^{\mu}}{2}\right)P\psi$$

The result that I get is the following:

$$p'^{\mu}=(p^{0},-\vec{p})$$
$$s'^{\mu}=(-s^{0},\vec{s})$$

I think the primed energy momentum 4-vector is the correct one, but i'm not sure about the polarization.

Is this procedure correct? How should I interpret this result?

Answer (score 0):

You should  try and see what $P\psi$, or simply $\gamma_0\psi$, becomes for a general Dirac 4-spinor. Moreover don't put the sign into the polarisation vector, just leave the second parenthesis as $$\gamma_0\left(\frac{1+\gamma_5\not s}{2}\right) = \left(\frac{1-\gamma_5\not s}{2}\right)\gamma_0$$

Comment: I think that what you wrote is not correct, because $\gamma^{0}$ anticommutes with $\gamma_{5}$, but it anticommutes also with the three matrices $\gamma^{i}$ which are contained in the symbol s with slash. As a result, the minus sign appears only for the 0-th component of the polarization 4-vector. Tell me if I'm wrong.